# Adobe Air stop(); doesn't seem to work

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, flash-cs5

When I work on my Air Project, I used stop(); to stay in a frame(which is my menu), I built the .air for testing purposes and the frames keep looping, as in, it plays all the frames, and it won't stop as it's instructed to.

Is there anything wrong? I'm building my Application in Flash CS5, not Flex. Thanks for helping!

Comment: are you using stage.stop() or this.stop() or myControl.stop() ??? please share some code

Comment: confirmed - stop() does not seem to work on Flash CS5 Publish to Air ...

Comment: Where is the code? In the timeline, a class? We'll need specifics to help..

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before when I tried to stop a MovieClip which contained other MovieClips. Is this possibly the case with you?

If it is, be sure to call stop on each of the MovieClips internally.

EDIT: You also need to check your syntax. I had one MovieClip that wouldn't stop, and I found a typo in the gotoAndStop call for it inside an event handler that hadn't even fired.